# In Elixir, placing test files alongside their related modules

Tags: elixir, ex-unit

Is it possible in elixir to have my test modules in the same directory as the modules they are testing?

A typical Elixir project has a structure like this:

```
project
|-- lib
|   `-- my_module.ex
`-- test
    |-- my_module_test.exs
    `-- test_helper.exs
```

When writing node projects I like to have my test modules next to the modules they are testing. This is easily configarable using tools like Jest:

```
project
|-- lib
|   |-- my_module.ex
|   `-- my_module.test.exs
`-- test
    `-- test_helper.exs
```

Is it possible to have a similar setup in Elixir/Exunit?

Comment: Yes, this is possible. Elixir compiler does not care about where your files are located in the directory tree. Literally, you might put everything in the root folder.

Comment: Indeed, my question was really about the *how* as by default Exunit looks in the `test` directory for tests?

Comment: It turned out I was wrong. [Invoking `mix test` from the command line will run the tests in each file matching the pattern `*_test.exs` found in the **`test`** directory of your project](https://hexdocs.pm/ex_unit/ExUnit.html#module-integration-with-mix).

Comment: So I guess the test pattern is not configurable. That is a shame

Comment: It depends on what approach is taken. I prefer to use standards rather than to invent my own squared wheels. After all, [I believe] nobody in Elixir community wants to meet a project that has tests mixed with code.

Comment: That's fair enough - although in node it's quite common to have your tests next to code. But agree that sticking to standard is better. As an aside I found this which suggests it might be configurable: https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/165048513d84473a628220bb533dc726d98ac314/lib/mix/lib/mix/tasks/test.ex#L367-L373

Comment: Good catch! Then if you insist on doing node in elixir just put `test_paths: "."` into `project` callback of your `mix.exs`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OK, I’ll put it as an answer for the sake of future visitors.

Mix documentation [explicitly states](https://hexdocs.pm/ex_unit/ExUnit.html#module-integration-with-mix)

> Invoking `mix test` from the command line will run the tests in each file matching the pattern `*_test.exs` **found in the `test` directory** of your project.

It looks like `ExUnit` authors strongly discourage developers to put tests somewhere else. As @harryg discovered, it’s still possible, though. `project` settings have `tests_path` variable [that is checked for where tests are to be found](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/165048513d84473a628220bb533dc726d98ac314/lib/mix/lib/mix/tasks/test.ex#L367-L374) (and `test_pattern` for the pattern,) defaulted to `"test"` and 
`"*_test.exs"` respectively.

To reset it to some other value, simply update the `project` callback adding these two lines:

```rb
  def project do
    [
      app: @app,
      version: @version,
      elixir: "~> 1.6",
      start_permanent: Mix.env() == :prod,
      ...
      test_paths: ".",
      test_pattern: "*_test.exs" # or something else
    ]
  end
```